# Does biting ooze cause it to split?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

If a creature bites a [Verdurous Ooze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/ooze-verdurous) does it cause the creature to split (assuming it breaks the 10 damage threshold)?

Bite attacks count as B/P/S so we assumed it goes through the damage reduction and  our DM ruled that it would also split but we could not find RAW.

Comment: Good question. Same would apply to some weapons, eg Morningstar (B+P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes.

The split is caused by whatever *piercing* or *slashing* damage it takes, as long as at least 10 points of damage are caused by the attack.

[Bite attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks) are *Bludgeoning*, *Piercing* and *Slashing*, similar to a *morning star*, so you don't have the option to cause one or another, the weapon damage's type counts as all three types and any weapon based damage reduction will apply to them, allowing them to ignore it.

For a creature to reduce or be immune to a weapon's damage type, it has to reduce all of it, as noted on the [Weapon's Type](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#TOC-Weapon-Qualities):

> **Type**: Weapons are classified according to the type of damage they deal: B for bludgeoning, P for piercing, or S for slashing. Some monsters may be resistant or immune to attacks from certain types of weapons. Some weapons deal damage of **multiple types**. If a weapon causes two types of damage, the type it deals is not half one type and half another; all damage caused **is of both types**. Therefore, a creature would have to be immune to both types of damage to ignore any of the damage caused by such a weapon. In other cases, a weapon can deal either of two types of damage. In a situation where the damage type is significant, the wielder can choose which type of damage to deal with such a weapon.

The ooze should take this damage, as she is immune to slashing and piercing damage, but not *bludgeoning damage*, as noted by her *Defensive Abilities*:

> Defensive Abilities split; **Immune** acid, fire, mind-affecting effects, ooze traits, **slashing and piercing damage**

Comment: The [weapons](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/armsAndArmor/weapons.html#type) section states that immunity applies only if a creature has immunity to all kinds of damage a weapon deals. And the DR rules imply the same. That seems to contradict your statement that a bite is reduced by both 5/Piercing and 5/Slashing damage reductions. "Therefore, a creature would have to be immune to both types of damage to ignore any of the damage caused by such a weapon."

Comment: I see, so unless a creature is immune to weapon attacks (or all three types), bites will still cause damage.

Comment: Using the statement, " In a situation where the damage type is significant, the wielder can choose which type of damage to deal with such a weapon. " could the biter choose to only do bludgeoning damage thus bypassing damage reduction and not causing a split?

Comment: No, bite does all three types of damage, that clause is for weapons that have the *OR* clause, like a dagger that can do *S or P* (slashing or piercing).

Comment: Few weapons actually say *and*, the morning star on the weapon's table, and bites and claw attacks mostly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is piercing and/or slashing damage, so the Ooze's Split ability applies.